# How to create a class using prototype.js

Tags: javascript, oop, prototypejs

Could any one shows an example for creating a class using prototype.js and how it works.Can anyone provide good examples and tutorials for prototype.js other than its official site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating PrototypeJS Classes is very similar to creating classes in normal OOP languages.

First start off by naming your class

```
var myClass = Class.create({ });
```

This will create an empty class - now populate it with methods, if you put a method `initialize` PrototypeJS will fire that as the constructor

```
var myClass = Class.create(
{
    initialize : function()
    {
        this.options = 0;
    }
});
```

You can setup anything you want in the `initialize()` method like default values or just initializing the properties of the class. Lets put in some other methods and show how to instantiate the class.

```
var myClass = Class.create(
{
    initialize : function()
    {
        this.options = 0;
    },

    testme : function()
    {
        this.options++;
    },

    showme : function()
    {
        alert(this.options);
        return this.options;
    }
});

var theClass = new myClass();
```

Lets take it one more step and call other methods within methods and pass options to the constructor.

```
var myClass = Class.create(
{
    initialize : function(option)
    {
        this.options = (option ? option : 0);

        this.testme();
    },

    testme : function()
    {
        this.options++;
    },

    showme : function()
    {
        alert(this.options);
        return this.options;
    }
});

var theClass = new myClass(200);
theClass.showme();

//will alert 201 and return 201
```

This is cool and all - but what about class inheritance? That is a big thing in OOP - lets say we have a separate class that is a child class of `myClass`. For any method that you are overriding in the child class you can pass a first variable as `$super` and that will refer to the parent's method of the same name - similar to a scope resolution

```
var myChildClass = Class.create(myClass,
{
    initialize : function($super,option)
    {
        $super(option);

        // the child class needs option's default value at 150 or whatever is 
        // passed so run the parent initialize first and then redefine the 
        // option property
        this.option = (option ? option : 150);

        // you can still run methods in the parent that are not overridden in 
        // the child
        this.testme();
    }
});

var child = new myChildClass();
child.showme();

//will alert() 151 and return 151
```

I hope this is helpful for you.

Here are some more complex real world examples from my github

https://github.com/jwestbrook/Prototype.Growler

https://github.com/jwestbrook/Prototype.Watermark

https://github.com/jwestbrook/bootstrap-prototype

Comment: Can we create class only with prototype.js in pure html file or we need help of any other tools?

Comment: `Class.create()` is available in the PrototypeJS core library, you do not need any other javascript libraries to implement that method.

Comment: where we have to write the child class functions?in the same html page or in another?

Comment: You can create child classes in the same file as long as the new child class javascript is below the parent class, or as long as the parent class exists for the child class to inherit it.