# Prototype.js and idiom in code?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a lot of code that uses Prototype's [Object.extend](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/Object/extend/). It looks something like this...

```
var x = Class.create();
Object.extend(
    Object.extend( x.prototype, Ajax.Application.Base.prototype ),
    { ... stuff ... }
);
```

Now the signature for `Object.extend` is `Object.extend(destination, source) → Object`

So we're extending x.prototype with Ajax.Application.Base.prototype. Then we're extending that object (x.prototype).. with more stuff.

Is that the same as as a double extend()? What's the advantage of rolling them together?

Are these associative such that..

```
Object.extend(x,y); Object.extend(x,z) == Object.extend(Object.extend(x,y),z);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question - yes Object.extend does return the new object that has all the methods and properties of the 2 objects passed as parameters.

However there is a more useful and concise way to extend a PrototypeJS Class

(copying a bit from my other answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15527223/341491)

```
var myChildClass = Class.create(myClass,
{
    initialize : function($super,option)
    {
        $super(option);

        // the child class needs option's default value at 150 or whatever is 
        // passed so run the parent initialize first and then redefine the 
        // option property
        this.option = (option ? option : 150);

        // you can still run methods in the parent that are not overridden in 
        // the child
        this.testme();
    }
});

var child = new myChildClass();
child.showme();

//will alert() 151 and return 151
```

this will create a Class called myChildClass that is extended from myClass. The difference with this method is the ability to use the `$super()` method which points to the parent class.