# Inheritance in Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I have been read some information about javascript inheritance but i am not sure how to manage the following situation. Let's say i have an object A with the attribute 'b' and 'c'. Attribute 'b' is a class like this:

```
A.b=function(elements, tags) {
 this.elements = elements;
 this.tags = tags;
}
A.b.prototype.funct1 = function() { 
  alert('a');
}
```

I want attribute "c" to extends class "b" but to add some elements in constructor and define own functions.

```
A.c = function(elements,tags) {
  A.c.prototype = new A.b(elements,tags);
  this.var = null;
};

A.c.prototype.funct2 = function(){
 alert('funct2');
}
```

I am using Prototype js.
Can you tell if is bad practice or there is an elegant way to do this.

Comment: Nothing you showed here is related to PrototypeJS. Doesn't seem to be relevant that you are using it? Also, there are *many* questions about inheritance in JS already + tutorials on the Internet. None of them helped? For example: [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: @aduch: Well, depends. Did you *read* the question? ("Inhereance in Prototype JS",  "I am using prototype js."). OP might just have used the wrong tag for prototypejs, which coincidentally is the right tag for the problem.

Comment: The question keeps mentioning the Prototype JS library, but it looks like it is asking about prototypal OO in JS.

Comment: I specified PrototypeJs because i didn't want an answer like this "If you are using JS Node you should do like this" (this is an example)

Comment: Someone has ported the Prototype JS library to Node — https://github.com/rixius/prototype.node.js — so requiring Prototype JS (which doesn't appear remotely relevant) doesn't exclude Node.

Comment: I think the name of prototype JS is the only thing I dislike more in the language's ecosystem than the $ variable.

Comment: @Quentin oky, i am sorry if i created confusion.

Comment: Here is an answer I posted which does Class inheritance in PrototypeJS http://stackoverflow.com/a/15527223/341491