# Override js function which has arguments

Tags: javascript, overriding, prototypejs

I want to overwrite js method which has arguments.

Please check original js file   : bundle.js

```
Product.Bundle = Class.create();
Product.Bundle.prototype = {
    reloadPrice: function() {

         -----  Default Code  -----

    },
    selectionPrice: function(optionId, selectionId) {

         -----  Default Code  -----
    },
}
```

I have to overwrite both methods in my js file. I can successfully overwrite reloadPrice method in my js but can not overwrite selectionPrice
method.

Please check my js file code in which reloadPrice method is overwrite successfully

```
<script>
    Product.Bundle.prototype.reloadPrice =
        Product.Bundle.prototype.reloadPrice.wrap(function(parentMethod) {
            -----  Default Code  ------
        });


        // Doing same thnig for SelectionPrice method but not worked :
        Product.Bundle.prototype.selectionPrice =
            Product.Bundle.prototype.selectionPrice.wrap(function(parentMethod) {
            -----  Default Code  -----
        });
</script>
```

Where I am wrong.Please help me.

Comment: What is `Class.create()`? Should it be `Object.create()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have to overwrite method which has an arguments then you can overwrite that like below :

```
<script>
 Product.Bundle.prototype.selectionPrice =
     Product.Bundle.prototype.selectionPrice.wrap(function(parentMethod,optionId, selectionId)  {
        -----  Default Code  -----
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you might want to consider doing a subclass/child class to do the overriding http://stackoverflow.com/a/15527223/341491